# MVC validation not working as expected in popup window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I'm trying to utilize the built-in validation in MVC and it doesn't appear to be working. If I leave the fields in my form empty I get back my "Successfully Saved." message.

Shouldn't the fields that are 'Required' be marked as required in the form?

[image: Form Image]

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ACore.Asset assetForm)
    {
        var results = new
        {
            value = false,
            Message = ""
        };

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            results = new
            {
                value = true,
                Message = "Successfully Saved."
            };

            return Json(results);
        }

        results = new
        {
            value = false,
            Message = "Please check the form values."
        };

        return Json(results);
    }
```

View (condensed):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Asset", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="tempStyle">
        <div class="editor-label fl">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetName)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
    </div>
```

JavaScript that handles my save:

```
    var saveAsset = function (e) {
        var form = $("#frmAsset");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Asset/Create",
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.value == true) {
                    alert(data.Message);

                    // Close popup window
                    var window = $('#AssetEditorPopUp').data("kendoWindow");
                    window.close();

                    // Refresh grid to show changes
                    $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();

                    return;
                }

                alert(data.Message);

            },

            error: function () {
                alert("There was an error editing the asset.");
            }
        });
    };
```

Model:

```
public class Asset
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int AssetId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Asset Name:")]
    public string AssetName { get; set; }

    public string AssetFormerName { get; set; }
    public string Seg1Code { get; set; }
    public string Seg3Code { get; set; }
    public bool? ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string AssetType { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "ZipCode:")]
    [RegularExpression("([a-zA-Z0-9 .&'-]+)", ErrorMessage = "Enter only alphabets and numbers of First Name")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is what I get doing a POST rather than ajax.

[image]

Comment: Interesting problem.  As a matter of interest do you also have client validation enabled?  Check for ClientValidationEnabled in web.config

Comment: Also does the validation work if you do a normal POST rather than using Ajax?

Comment: Client validation is enabled in my web.config. I'll try a normal POST and I'll post back here.

Comment: I added an image above to show the results of the POST. It appears validation isn't working still.

Comment: This sounds like the issue I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773938/kendo-ui-mvc-4-form-validation-inside-a-window-does-not-fire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your button is set to be of type button, it should be submit.  you aren't firing the forms submit handler, so validation isn't being performed.

create your form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Asset", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmAsset"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<div class="tempStyle">
    <div class="editor-label fl">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AssetName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AssetName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AssetName)
    </div>
</div>
<div style="position: relative;">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
</div>
```

Then you can use the following javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $("#frmAsset").submit(function(evt){
        var form = $(evt.currentTarget);

        if(form.validate().isvalid()
        {
             // your handler here
        }
        evt.preventDefault();  // prevent the form from posting normally
        return false;
    };
};
```

I would look at the AJAX.BeginForm helper, it is more suited to what you are doing here.

nb.  I haven't typed this in the ide, so i don't know if it is 100% valid, you will need to test it.